# Oracle Select From JSON Array

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table for some 'settings' and in that table I have a record with a json array. It is a simple array, like this:

```
"['scenario1','scenario2','scenario3']"
```

I want to use a sub-select statement in a view to pull this information out so I can use it like this:

```
select * from table where field_scenario in (select ????? from settings_table where this=that)
```

I have been looking through documentation and googling for this but for the life of me I can't figure out how to 'pivot' the returning array into individual elements in order to use it.

Oracle 12c I believe, thanks in advance.

Comment: `"['scenario1','scenario2','scenario3']"` is not a JSON array; it is a JSON string. `['scenario1','scenario2','scenario3']` (without the surrounding quotes) would be a JSON array (and to strictly meet [the syntax](https://www.json.org/) it should be double quotes but most parsers are permissive and allow both single- and double-quotes) .

Answer (score 2):

Do **NOT** use regular expression to parse JSON. Use a proper JSON parser:

```sql
select *
from   table_name
where  field_scenario in (
  SELECT j.value
  FROM   settings_table s
         OUTER APPLY (
           SELECT value
           FROM   JSON_TABLE(
             s.json,
             '$[*]'
             COLUMNS(
               value VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$'
             )
           )
         ) j
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE settings_table ( json CLOB CHECK ( json IS JSON ) );
INSERT INTO settings_table ( json ) VALUES ( '["scenario1","scenario2","scenario3"]');
INSERT INTO settings_table ( json ) VALUES ( '["scenario5"]');
INSERT INTO settings_table ( json ) VALUES ( '["scenario \"quoted\""]');
INSERT INTO settings_table ( json ) VALUES ( '["scenario2,scenario4"]');

CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, field_scenario ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'scenario'||LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'scenario "quoted"' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | FIELD_SCENARIO   
> -: | :----------------
>  1 | scenario1        
>  2 | scenario2        
>  3 | scenario3        
>  5 | scenario5        
>  7 | scenario "quoted"
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5eec8c956081acd955eb08c2f01c68f5)*

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked a treat. Really appreciate it. I didn't anticipate pulling that information back out would require such a complex query, but I'm very new to json.

Comment: OK I hate to come back here, but this worked well in my initial simple test. However when I baked it into the view, I am getting an error "no more data to read from socket". I took those lines out and put the hard coded data back in and it worked just fine. Any ideas?